# Pandas: Key error when doing merge_asof on datetime index and one more column

Tags: pandas, datetime, merge

When trying to merge on datatime index two dataframes i get `KeyError: DatetimeIndex`. I tried to merge with duplicates and without in left data frame and  still get the same error. What is wrong?

```
print(news_df_sep.info())
DatetimeIndex: 55332 entries, 2020-01-02 13:00:00.824000+00:00 to 2020-04-15 02:43:28.876000+00:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   stock_id   55332 non-null  int64 
 1   headlines  55332 non-null  object


print(y_df.info())
DatetimeIndex: 7591265 entries, 2011-02-24 09:30:00.070041845 to 2020-04-02 14:59:59.938843711
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column      Dtype  
---  ------      -----  
 0   stock_id    int64  
 1   BestPlayY2  float64

print(type(news_df_sep.index), type(y_df.index)) 
(pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex,
 pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex)

print(sum(news_df_sep.index.duplicated()), sum(y_df.index.duplicated())
(182, 0)

df_t = news_df_sep.drop_duplicates()
print(df_t.info())

DatetimeIndex: 54584 entries, 2020-01-02 13:00:00.824000+00:00 to 2020-04-15 02:43:28.876000+00:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   stock_id   54584 non-null  int64 
 1   headlines  54584 non-null  object
```

Merge:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df_t, y_df, on=df_t.index, by='stock_id')
```

Result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-323-cd5352c971ef> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.merge_asof(df_t, y_df, on=df_t.index, by='stock_id')

~/anaconda3/envs/py37jp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge_asof(left, right, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, by, left_by, right_by, suffixes, tolerance, allow_exact_matches, direction)
    537         tolerance=tolerance,
    538         allow_exact_matches=allow_exact_matches,
--> 539         direction=direction,
    540     )
    541     return op.get_result()

~/anaconda3/envs/py37jp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, by, left_by, right_by, axis, suffixes, copy, fill_method, how, tolerance, allow_exact_matches, direction)
   1565             how=how,
   1566             suffixes=suffixes,
-> 1567             fill_method=fill_method,
   1568         )
   1569 

~/anaconda3/envs/py37jp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, axis, suffixes, copy, fill_method, how)
   1455             how=how,
   1456             suffixes=suffixes,
-> 1457             sort=True,  # factorize sorts
   1458         )
   1459 

~/anaconda3/envs/py37jp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    625             self.right_join_keys,
    626             self.join_names,
--> 627         ) = self._get_merge_keys()
    628 
    629         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

~/anaconda3/envs/py37jp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
   1622 
   1623         # note this function has side effects
-> 1624         (left_join_keys, right_join_keys, join_names) = super()._get_merge_keys()
   1625 
   1626         # validate index types are the same

~/anaconda3/envs/py37jp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
    972                     else:
    973                         if rk is not None:
--> 974                             right_keys.append(right._get_label_or_level_values(rk))
    975                             join_names.append(rk)
    976                         else:

~/anaconda3/envs/py37jp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1690             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1691         else:
-> 1692             raise KeyError(key)
   1693 
   1694         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-02 13:00:00.824000+00:00',
               '2020-01-08 11:02:52.833000+00:00',
               '2020-01-10 03:41:18.858000+00:00',
               '2020-01-16 13:00:01.404000+00:00',
               '2020-01-22 13:00:01.560000+00:00',
               '2020-01-23 13:00:01.493000+00:00',
               '2020-01-27 14:38:26.199000+00:00',
               '2020-01-27 19:00:00.580000+00:00',
               '2020-01-28 21:30:02.279000+00:00',
               '2020-01-29 14:33:16.401000+00:00',
               ...
               '2020-03-24 20:13:27.745000+00:00',
               '2020-03-24 20:13:39.192000+00:00',
               '2020-03-24 20:14:05.710000+00:00',
               '2020-03-24 22:42:35.011000+00:00',
               '2020-03-25 21:20:00.820000+00:00',
               '2020-03-25 21:20:05.833000+00:00',
               '2020-03-25 21:20:47.132000+00:00',
               '2020-04-06 18:58:34.410000+00:00',
               '2020-04-13 15:40:07.672000+00:00',
               '2020-04-15 02:43:28.876000+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='date', length=54584, freq=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

> ```
> on : label
>
> Field name to join on. Must be found in both DataFrames. The data MUST be ordered. Furthermore this must be a numeric column, such as
> datetimelike, integer, or float. On or left_on/right_on must be given.
> ```

It is complaining because you are giving it values instead of a name of a column to join on.

If you want to join on indices, just do `df = pd.merge_asof(df_t, y_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, by='stock_id')`.

In your case however you will need to match the time zones of your indices first, one is UTC and the other none, either go with `df_t.index = df_t.index.tz_convert(None)` or `y_df.index = y_df.index.tz_localize('UTC')`.

Comment: How then to join on dataframe index?

Comment: Pass it left_index=True, right_index=True
You'll have to make the indices have the same time zone though, so either you do .tz_convert(None) on the df_t index or .tz_convert('UTC') on the y_df one before merging.

Comment: I get: 1) df_t.index.tz_convert(None) # atributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'tz_convert' 2)
y_df.index.tz_convert('UTC') #Cannot convert tz-naive timestamps, use tz_localize to localize

Comment: Oh yeah sorry tz_localize for y_df, and for df_t you should then first do df_t.index = pd.to_datetime(df_t.index)

Comment: In this case, after `df_t.index = pd.to_datetime(df_t.index)` I get "Cannot convert tz-naive timestamps, use tz_localize to localize"

Comment: Well then use tz_localize, but it does not match with what I could see in your original question.
If you end up using tz_localize on both, you don't have to use it at all as it implies they were both timezone-naive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212264/discussion-between-v-dehaye-and-dokondr).